# Aggregating the result of a ForkJoin in Rx

Tags: .net, system.reactive, reactive-programming

Given this piece of code:

```
var loadAll =
   Observable.ForkJoin(
      service1.FindBooksAsObservable().Select(s => s),
      service2.FindBooksAsObservable().Select(s => s),
      service3.FindBooksAsObservable().Select(s => s)
);

loadAll.Subscribe(
   result =>
   {
      var aggregatedListOfBooks = result.SelectMany(b => b);
   });
```

As you can see, the problem is each *FindBooksAsObservable()* method returns an `IObservable<IEnumerable<Book>>`, thus the *result* variable in the *Subscribe()* is an Array of `IEnumerable<Book>`.

Is there any other way of aggregating the result of the *ForkJoin()*? I was hoping to use something like *Merge()* along with the ForkJoin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming all three services return a list of `Books`, you can use `SelectMany` to merge the lists:

```
IObservable<Book> loadAll = 
    Observable.ForkJoin(
        service1.FindBooksAsObservable().Select(s => s),
        service2.FindBooksAsObservable().Select(s => s),
        service3.FindBooksAsObservable().Select(s => s)
    )
    .Select(books => books.SelectMany(list => list).ToList());

loadAll.Subscribe(
    book => { /* will be called once with a single list of all items */ });
```

You can remove the `ToList()` call if you don't require the output to be a list.

Comment: No, actually want i'd like is to receive all the books from all the services in a single list.

Comment: @maelcumx - See updated, though I've assumed that you don't need to remove duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

`Observable.ForkJoin` is not on the latest stable version of Reactive Extensions (Rx) (v2.1.30214.0). The ForkJoin as of now June 2013, is only in the experimental versions of Rx.

Dave Sexton suggested a work around:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/rx/thread/3cfccb74-9ce3-47dc-94fd-cf60270c1ed5